# show list without tying in select2 ajax jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 ajax based jQuery to show dropdown. Its working perfectly. Now I want  when user clicks on the select2 box without typing then it will show 10 records. I am using InitSelection, but it didn't show anything. Code is:-

```
var tags = [
            {'id':1, 'text':'Ben'},  
            {'id':22, 'text':'Andrea'}
    ];
    $('#form_fb_q').select2({       
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        ajax: {
            url: "/provisioning/api/facebook/default/",
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 250,
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term,
                    method: $('input[name=fb_search_by]:checked').attr('method')
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                return {
                    results: data.data
                };
            }
        },
        formatResult : function (entry) {
            var markup = "<table class='entry-result'><tr>";
            markup += '<td class="entry-image"><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/' + entry.id + '/picture?type=square"/></td>';
            markup += "<td class='entry-info'><div class='entry-name'>" + entry.name + "</div>";
            markup += "<div class='entry-likes'>" + entry.likes + " likes</div>";
            markup += "</td></tr></table>";
            return markup;
        },
                    initSelection: function(element, callback) {
                       // alert("hahaha");
                    callback(tags);
                    },
        formatSelection : function (entry) {
            return entry.name;
        },
        dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop",
        escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }

    });
```

Input box is :-

```
 <input id="form_fb_q"  name="fb_q"  value="111" >
```

Please help me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change
    `minimumInputLength: 2`
to
    `minimumInputLength: 0`

this way your ajax will be called on initial drop down of the control.  your current configuration is only making the ajax call once there are two letters typed in.